# How to stop the internal result pointer from moving forward in pg_fetch_result or pg_fetch_array

Tags: php, postgresql

We are trying to upgrade a php application of our client written by another vendor. One of the roadblock we have encounter is in the use of **pg_fetch_result**/**pg_fetch_array** in some of the code. Consider the example:

```
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT user_name, user_add, mobile FROM user_profile WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3");    
$username = pg_fetch_result($result, "user_name"); // print 1st user name
$address = pg_fetch_result($result, "user_add"); // print 2nd user address, expected 1st
$mobile = pg_fetch_result($result, "mobile"); // print 3rd user mobile, expected 1st
```

How is the internal pointer moving forward? Is there a way to stop the pointer from moving forward?

Comment: you can just use `$arr = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);` then access the keys according to your defined columns, like so: `$arr['user_name']` and `$arr['user_add']` and so on

Comment: @Kevin thank you for your response. We will use your answer and see that we can fine-tune it for our project.